# Can we use a reading fd and writing fd in dup2 as arguments

Tags: unix, polling

Can we use a reading file descriptor as the first argument and writing file descriptor as second argument in a call to dup2(), so that the the output from the second file descriptor is redirected to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `dup2` closes the second file descriptor if it's open. It doesn't hook the two file descriptors together.

You might be able to use the `sendfile` or `splice` system calls to copy the data on Linux, or `sendfile` on OS X, without moving it through your process address space. However, these calls don't magically copy all the data without blocking your process.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Look at the man page for `pipe`(2)